# How to create a custom block from billing.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, widget

I would like to add a new block in the customer registration, edit and billing forms. This block will contain a dropdown control where the customer can select if he wants to register as a company or as an individual.

At first, I edited billing.phtml and added the following:

```
<li class="fields">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('mynamespace/mymodule/customer/widget/registeras.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
</li>
```

This is working fine, but instead of using 'core/template', I would like to create my custom typed block.

I wrote this in the config:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Widget_Registeras</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

Then I created the class of my block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Widget_Registeras extends Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        // default template location
        $this->setTemplate('mynamespace/mymodule/customer/widget/registeras.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Get current customer from session
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

Now I replaced:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('mynamespace/mymodule/customer/widget/registeras.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

by this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mynamespace_mymodule/widget_registeras')->setObject($this->getQuote()->getCustomer())->toHtml(); ?>
```

But it's not working. Here is the error I get:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid block type:
>   Mage_Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Widget_Registeras' in
>   E:\myworkspace\magento\app\Mage.php:595 Stack trace:
>   0 E:\myworkspace\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495):
>   Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>   1 E:\myworkspace\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('mynamespace_my...', Array)
>   2 E:\myworkspace\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('mynamespace_my...',
>   'widget_register...')
>   ...

I could not understand why magento adds 'Mage_' to the class name.

I also tried to load it using the layout and getChildHtml() but I could not get it work better.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/widget_registeras')->setObject($this->getQuote()->getCustomer())->toHtml(); ?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: Thank you but it is not working. I got the same error as above ('Mage_' is added at the beginning of the class, I guess because billing.phtm is a mage block..) + I get a second error: exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Widget_Registeras_Widget_Registeras' => this time 'Mage_' is not added but '_Widget_Registeras' is written twice.. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Typically Magento will prepend "Mage_" if you don't have your `<blocks>` set up quite right in the **config.xml**.

Try replacing this...

```
    <blocks>
        <mymodule>
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Widget_Registeras</class>
        </mymodule>
    </blocks>
```

with this...

```
    <blocks>
        <mymodule>
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mymodule>
    </blocks>
```

Also, when you are calling `createBlock()` you will use just `"mymodule/widget_registeras"` like Asish Hira says.  The first part of that before the slash `/` will reference the `<mymodule>` you set up inside your `<blocks>` of the **config.xml**